# roots of several polynomial functions

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

I have the following problem: Let $p_1(x_1,\cdots,x_m),\cdots,p_m(x_1,\cdots,x_m):\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$ be polynomials with real coefficients and over $m$ real variables.

We want to find $z=(z_1,\cdots,z_m)\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$p_1(z_1,\cdots,z_m)=0 $$
$$p_2(z_1,\cdots,z_m)=0  $$
$$\vdots $$
$$p_m(z_1,\cdots,z_m)=0 $$

Suppose you have some $y=(y_1,\cdots,y_m)$ which you believe to be near such $z$, for example you obtained $y$ numerically by minimizing the sum of the squares of the $p_i$ and it gets very near zero. Is there a way to check numerically, that $y$ is indeed near such $z$? I've read about the [Poincaré–Miranda theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Miranda_theorem), but unfortunately it doesnt give an algorithm which guarantees that you are near some solution (the theorem requires you to check an infinite number of points).

Any help appreciated. Thanks!